# is this an example of acts as a prepositional phrase?

Tags: vocabulary, american-english, british-english, interpretation, learning

watching this interview posted on YouTube yesterday with Paul McCartney:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=21pcVuPHoek

from 7:26 Paul McCartney

says: "I owe it to him and his team who were briliant and use a lot of great technology of just enhancing the film"

so that that confuses me is:

"use a lot of great technology of just enhancing the film"

at first I though he tried to say:

"use a lot of great technology TO just enhancing the film"

but I thin he would make that confusion. Any chance he used "of just enhancing the film" acts as a prepositional phrase and the meaning would be something like:

"of just enhancing the film him and his team who were briliant and use a lot"???

Comment: I think the speaker just "stumbled" over the sentence and added an unnecessary "of." It should have been, "I owe it to him and his team, who were brilliant and **used** a lot of great technology just enhancing the film." Notice there was also a tense inconsistency in the original (**were** brilliant vs. **use** a lot). This kind of mistake is very common in conversational speech, but would be edited out of formal writing.

Comment: @Quack E. Duck, that make sense. Please let me ask you this: if the original sentence were really: "of just enhancing the film they used a lot of technology" could i flip the phrases around like: "they used a lot of technology of just enhancing the film" and keep the same gist? my original question made me think about that!

Comment: You can't take a transcript of extemporaneous speech and critique it in the way you can with the written word. People of all languages mispronounce things, stumble over words, repeat themselves, use malapropisms, have word whiskers etc.

Comment: @Astralbee, I agree with you and as Quack E. Duck
 made clear that. this situation made me wander the scenario where having: "of just enhancing the film they used a lot of technology" someone could invert the phrases, for any purpose the speaker would have in mind, like: ""they used a lot of technology of just enhancing the film" and keep the same gist I mean if that would still be grammatically justified get it? I personally thinks the inversion would make sense and would force the reader to use some logic